# Unknown runtime error VBScripts - Write Formula into Excel

Tags: excel, vbscript

i'm trying put a formula in specific cell into a Excel, so i do a link between two excel for do this formula. I have this code, but i dont know, how use it for can obtein it that i will realize.
i'm amateur in this area and need to help for can do that.
my code is this

[image]

```
Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

app.Visible = True

app.Workbooks.Open("C:\MODERNO\REPORTES\RESUMENFACTURA.XLS")

app.Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 17).formula = "=INDEX([Moderno.XLS]ART015!$J:$J;MATCH(P2;  [Moderno.XLS]ART015!$P:$P;0))"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Write Formula to Excel

- Since we are creating a new Excel instance, it is assumed that both files are closed (or at least the destination file).
- The error is occurring because there is `app.Workbooks` but there is no `app.Worksheets` i.e. the 'parent-child' order is `Application - Workbook - Worksheet - Range`. You cannot skip one. You could have used something like

  ```
  app.Workbooks(app.Workbooks.Count).Worksheets(1)...
  ```

  but since we want to do other stuff with the workbook, it is easier (more readable) to use a variable (see `dwb` in the code) or alternatively the [`With statement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement).
- Also, the formula is wrong. You cannot use the source workbook name without its path unless the workbook is open. To open it, you need to know its path. In VBA, you need to use commas instead of semicolons when using the [`Range.Formula property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formula). To use semicolons, you can use the [`Range.FormulaLocal property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formulalocal). To allow the path, the file, or the worksheet name to have spaces, you need to use single quotes (`'`) in the formula.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

WriteFormula

Sub WriteFormula

    Const SourceFolderPath = "C:\MODERNO\REPORTES" ' adjust!
    Const SourceFileName = "Moderno.XLS"
    Const DestinationFolderPath = "C:\MODERNO\REPORTES"
    Const DestinationFileName = "RESUMENFACTURA.XLS" 
    
    Dim DestinationFilePath
    DestinationFilePath = DestinationFolderPath & "\" & DestinationFileName

    Dim app: Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    app.Visible = True
    
    Dim dwb: Set dwb = app.Workbooks.Open(DestinationFilePath)
    On Error Resume Next
        dwb.UpdateLink dwb.LinkSources
    On Error GoTo 0
    dwb.Worksheets(1).Range("Q2").Formula _
        = "=INDEX('" & SourceFolderPath & "\[" & SourceFileName _
        & "]ART015'!$J:$J,MATCH(P2,'" & SourceFolderPath _
        & "\[" & SourceFileName & "]ART015'!$P:$P,0))"
    dwb.Close True
    
    app.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: First, thank you so mucho for your help, so, i have a question, If I want to do this formula for all Q column, put .Range("Q") it would solve this?

Comment: You can't do that but you could do `.Range("Q2:Q100").Formula`...

Comment: Excuse me i need to do this iteration for column Q yes, but, with column P is the same way, so, where are P2, should be P2 then P3 then P4...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. No need to iterate. You just need to replace `"Q2"` with e.g. `"Q2:Q100"`. Run the code and see for yourself how the formula is written to the range.

Comment: I need to iterate column Q, but i also need to iterate P, where are P2 i have to do it for P3, P4 P5 etc